# SQL FOR XML Repeating Root Node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to use the SQL FOR XML clause to generate custom XML as an output to use in SSIS. I'm extremely close. I can't find anything on the "type" option. For some reason "type" gets me close. Help is very much appreciated. **The desired output is this.**

```
<NLS CommitBlock="1" EnforceTagExistence="1">
  <LOAN loannumber="892127" acctrefno="145415" />
  <LOAN loannumber="892130" acctrefno="145418" />
  <LOAN loannumber="892131" acctrefno="145419" />
</NLS>
```

**The output I am getting is this.**

```
<NLS CommitBlock="1" EnforceTagExistence="1">
  <LOAN loannumber="892127" acctrefno="145415" />
</NLS>
<NLS CommitBlock="1" EnforceTagExistence="1">
  <LOAN loannumber="892130" acctrefno="145418" />
</NLS>
<NLS CommitBlock="1" EnforceTagExistence="1">
  <LOAN loannumber="892131" acctrefno="145419" />
</NLS>
```

**My SQL is this.**

```
SELECT  TOP (3) 
'1' AS 'CommitBlock',
'1' AS 'EnforceTagExistence',
(SELECT
vw_deferments.loan_number AS '@loannumber',
vw_deferments.acctrefno AS '@acctrefno'
FOR XML Path('LOAN'), type)
FROM            vw_deferments INNER JOIN
                loanacct ON vw_deferments.acctrefno = Iloanacct.acctrefno
WHERE (vw_deferments.Loan_Status IN ('PAYING', 'REPO REVIEW', 'REPO ASSIGN')) 
-- tons of irrelevant AND clauses are here
FOR XML RAW('NLS')
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no DDL and sample data population provided, I came up with the following conceptual example.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, loannumber VARCHAR(10), acctrefno VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl (loannumber, acctrefno)
VALUES
('892127','145415')
,('892130','145418')
,('892131','145419');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT TOP(1) '1' AS [@CommitBlock], '1' AS [@EnforceTagExistence]
, (
    SELECT loannumber AS [@loannumber]
        , acctrefno AS [@xacctrefno]
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('LOAN'), TYPE
)
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('NLS'), TYPE;
```

> Output

```
<NLS CommitBlock="1" EnforceTagExistence="1">
  <LOAN loannumber="892127" xacctrefno="145415" />
  <LOAN loannumber="892130" xacctrefno="145418" />
  <LOAN loannumber="892131" xacctrefno="145419" />
</NLS>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this with better indentation to clearly see what it's going to produce :

```
SELECT 
    [NLS/@CommitBlock]          = 1,
    [NLS/@EnforceTagExistence]  = 1,
    [NLS] = (
             SELECT
                    [@loannumber] = vw_deferments.loan_number,
                    [@acctrefno]  = vw_deferments.acctrefno
             FROM vw_deferments
             JOIN loanacct ON vw_deferments.acctrefno = Iloanacct.acctrefno
             WHERE 
                  (vw_deferments.Loan_Status IN ('PAYING', 'REPO REVIEW', 'REPO ASSIGN')) 
                  -- -- tons of irrelevant AND clauses are here
             FOR XML PATH('LOAN'), type
            )
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Nice method too. Please contact me on LInkedIn.